# How to see a history of "define" words which I used?

Tags: iphone, dictionary, history

I wanted to see the history of define dictionary words which I used in my iPhone but  I could not find a way to see it. Is there any option in iPhone to see it?

Comment: Not sure what you asking, do you want to look up words you added to the custom dictionary or what?

Comment: I can look up dictionary. Since i(and my friends) am not native english speaker, we like to share what we learn past few days. We want to know how we see history of words for which we have used define dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to see which words you have looked up previously in the dictionary using the "Define" shortcut in various apps.